# What is the criterion of model validation?

Tags: modeling, validation

Suppose I have a model that boasts given 1 year's daily data to calibrate the parameters, it could predict the behavior of future 1 month.

What should be the criterion for back-testing or, model validation?

Currently I calculate the error residuals and do Hypothesis testing:

1. Calculate $\epsilon = x - \hat x$ , where $x$ is the realized value, and $\hat x$ is the estimated value based on the model $X(\theta)$ , while $\theta$ are those parameters calibrated based on 1 year's data.
2. Since the model declares $\epsilon$ follows normal distribution:
   $$E\{\epsilon\} = 0$$
   and 
   $$Var\{\epsilon\} = \sigma^2 $$
   I do the Hypothesis testing on the next month's data (28-31 days).

Now, suppose I did such Hypothesis testing on the previous 5 years, during the 60 times hypothesis testing (significance level $\alpha=5\%$), 2 times failure in testing $E\{\epsilon\} = 0$, and 3 times failure in testing $Var\{\epsilon\} = \sigma^2 $, where there is a "bad month" both mean test and variance test failed.

Should I accept this model or reject it and request improvement?

Is there some guidelines or common practice on such issue?

Comment: Why should $\epsilon = \hat x$ - x follow a gaussian distribution? In general this is not the case. Thre are often outliers or bigger tails than a normal distribution.

Comment: let's say my model is $dx/x = \mu dt + \sigma dW$, so $\epsilon = \hat x - x = \sigma dW$ so it follows gaussian distribution. of course this is from the assumption of the model. I do have problem as the outliers often make my model failed the hypothesis test -- there are just way too many fat tails! any suggestion on that?

Comment: What is the cost if you use the model and it makes a bad prediction? How expensive is it to request improvements?

Comment: @momeara under current global financial crisis situation, the cost is not much big, maybe my bonus, maybe my job :p OK, seriously, the consideration is not the effort of improving the model, which is the next step, but, a criterion to say whether the model need improvement. i'm submitting a model, not only the numbers, but also a process of model setup, calibration, and validation, where the criterion kicks in. I need make the criterion reasonable, to cover my ass.